# Continuous calls to a URL causing exception to occur : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, httpwebrequest, webresponse

Following is the code snippet which i am trying to execute for an application i need. I am logging the couts till which the server is not throwing exception
But the counter (i) which i have provided goes till 170-190 records.

```
            for (int j = 0; j < 1000 ; j++)
            {
                i++;
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
                request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            var htmlString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            partialViews.Add(MvcHtmlString.Create(htmlString));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

What incorrect thing i am doing ? Is there any way to get the html strings from different application urls continuosly in such loops.

I have also tried using `WebClient` class for the same instead of `WebRequest` and `WebResponse`

Comment: What is the 500 error?

Comment: Hi Chris, there is no inner exception. The only error message being logged is "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error" . Source: System

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this error from constant contact API v(1).  This seems to randomly happen when I connect to check the status of my activities.  What I dois to sleep for 30 seconds, and retry the call.  I set this in a loop that will call it a maximum of 10 times.  I have never had to call it more than 3.

You will want to catch the 500 error off of your GetResponse (I have pasted only my process request code below).  You will probably need to adjust this code a bit for your needs:

```
        //this is used to call cc multiple times if it returns 500 errors
    public int _iWexCounter;
```

...

```
//Process the webrequest
 private string ProcessRequest()
    {

        string sResponse = string.Empty;


        try
        {


            HttpWebResponse ccResponse = (HttpWebResponse)_myWebRequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ccResponse.GetResponseStream());


            sResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // Close Reader
            reader.Close();


            // Close the response to free up the system resources
            ccResponse.Close();

            //the connect to CC was good, reset the wex error counter = 0 
            _iWexCounter = 0;
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            //if the cc server returns a 500, try to connect to it 10 times before blowing it all up
            if (wex.Message == "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.")
            {
                _iWexCounter++;
                if (_iWexCounter > 10)
                {

                    // Get the web exception type, error number returned here
                    sResponse = "Web Exception: " + wex.Status + wex.Message + wex.StackTrace + wex.GetBaseException().Message + wex.GetBaseException().StackTrace + sResponse;

                    SetConstantContactDifferentialAddTracker(_iConstantContactDifferentialAddTrackerID, "FAILURE", sResponse);

                    _sMessages.Append(wex.Message + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                else
                {
                    sResponse = "500 retry";
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Get the web exception type, error number returned here
            sResponse = "General Exception: " + ex.Message;

            SetConstantContactDifferentialAddTracker(_iConstantContactDifferentialAddTrackerID, "FAILURE", sResponse);

            _sMessages.Append(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        return sResponse;
    }
```